# The fee to interact with my contract is extremely high

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, mist, contract-invocation

I have an smart contract, the clasic crowdfunding contract where you send ether and receive tokens.

I want to send 0.1 from my wallet to make a test, but once I write the contract address, the information of the fee goes to 1.3 ether. I think that it is too much, for any contract!

[image]

I want to know where is the problem:

1) At my contract?
2) At my wallet? 
3) Probably nowadays the gas prices are very high and that fee is normal but I think that hardly can be.

I believe it isn't the contract because I have tested pasting different addresses from different contracts and it is always the same, the fee skyrockets.

Could the problem be that I synced my wallet in light mode? I have no more ideas. Probably it is something very simple.

Comment: If you're seeing this no matter what contract you try to send ether to, then it's an issue with the tool you're using (Mist, I believe?). Per https://www.ethgasstation.info/, a standard transaction fee these days is on the order of 0.00008 ether.

Comment: Yes, I'm using mist and syncing with geth. What could be the problem?

Comment: What does "show more options" do? Does it tell you the gas limit and gas price that it's using?

Comment: no, "show more options" only enables the data field.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas; I haven't used Mist much at all. I'd recommend https://www.myetherwallet.com (with MetaMask to avoid having to share your private key).

Comment: Is your contract source public to examine the cost of the operation?